# How do you remove In []: from an HTML Jupyter Notebook output?

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, tags

In the HTML output of any Jupyter Notebook `.ipynb`, I see `In []:` next to each code block. What is it and how do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: That's not a Markdown thing. Sounds like you might be talking about Jupyter notebooks or similar?

Comment: You are completely correct ...